# Cross Object References Workfront text editor

Tags: text-editor, attask, workfront-api

Hello I am attempting to link data that is connected to a task on a project report using the text editor.

So far I have this as my code:

```
displayname=Recvd Medical Rates
linkedname=project:tasks
namekey=DE:Documentation Received Date
querysort=project:tasks:Document - Medical Rates:Documentation Received Date
textmode=true
valuefield=Documentation Received Date
valueformat=customDateAsString
```

I need to display data from a specific task within a specific custom form on a project report. I know there is no standard method of linking a project with a task, but the relationship is there and from my research It seems possible. I believe that I do not have the correct syntax.

Can somebody please help me with this. I have tried all types of combinations, I even tried adding the aggregator:

```
aggregator.displayformat=customDateAsString
aggregator.function=MIN 
aggregator.namekey=Documentation Received Date
aggregator.valuefield=DE:Documentation Received Date
aggregator.valueformat=customDateAsAtDate
```

Either way I try and link the information the actual entered data will not display. So far the report knows that it is a date field; I know this because I am able click into the field on the project report and choose a date, but the date will not remain selected once I have chosen it leading me to believe that the field is somehow linked, but done incorrectly.

Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is below:

```
displayname=Plans and Benefits Received
listdelimiter=&#xfeff;
listmethod=nested(tasks).lists
textmode=true
type=iterate
valueexpression=IF(CONTAINS("Plans and Benefits",{name}),{actualCompletionDate})
valueformat=HTML
```

So how does it work? see below.

```
displayname=Plans and Benefits Received
```

^display name that you want^

```
listdelimiter=&#xfeff;
```

^decides delimiter^

```
listmethod=nested(tasks).lists
```

^Calls the nested or sub task^

```
textmode=true
```

^allows text editor mode to function^

```
type=iterate
```

^make data display as an iteration of original^

```
valueexpression=IF(CONTAINS("Plans and Benefits",{name}),{actualCompletionDate})
```

^determines where the data is being pulled from^

```
valueformat=HTML
```

^Format set to HTML^